# OpenGL/Libgdx scissors

Tags: opengl, libgdx, clipping

I am trying in libgdx to stop the rendering of actors outside of a group, as well as some rectangles inside the group, an example is below

```
----------------------
----------------------
--******************--
--******************--
--*****--------*****--
--******************--
--******************--
----------------------
----------------------
```

The group is defined as `*` which is where I would like actors drawn, `-` is where I would like actors clipped.

I have managed using the below code to clip any actors outside of the group;

```
Rectangle scissors = new Rectangle();
Rectangle clipBounds = new Rectangle(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
ScissorStack.calculateScissors(screen.getCamera(), screen.getBatch().getTransformMatrix(), clipBounds, scissors);
ScissorStack.pushScissors(scissors);
super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
batch.flush();
ScissorStack.popScissors();
```

How can I also clip actors inside the group (I have tried adding other clip bounds but it only renders sprites which are inside both clipbounds)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can nest an interior "anti-scissor" region inside a scissor region.  So you cannot, as far as I know, use the basic Libgdx/OpenGL primitives to accomplish this.

You can accomplish something similar by re-drawing the inner-most "------" region after drawing your actors (the "***" stuff).

Alternatively, you can probably use a Stencil Buffer or Depth Buffer or a custom Fragment Shader.  (See https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/LibGDX-Masking for ideas.)

Comment: Thanks for your input, so something like the methods found here? http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/ScreenUtils.html. I never thought of doing that, I am still learning so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

### **Implementation of own ScissorGroup**

---

### ScissorGroup:

```
class ScissorGroup(
   var maskRegion: TextureRegion? = null,
) : Group() {

override fun draw(batch: Batch?, parentAlpha: Float) {
    if (stage != null) {
        batch?.flush()
        drawScissor(batch, parentAlpha)
    }
}

private fun drawSuper(batch: Batch?, parentAlpha: Float) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha)
}

private fun drawScissor(batch: Batch?, parentAlpha: Float) {
    if (clipBegin(x, y, width, height)) {
        if (maskRegion != null) batch?.drawMask(parentAlpha) else drawSuper(batch, parentAlpha)
        clipEnd()
    }
}

private fun Batch.drawMask(parentAlpha: Float) {
    Gdx.gl.glColorMask(false, false, false, true)

    setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ZERO)

    setColor(0f, 0f, 0f, parentAlpha)
    draw(maskRegion, x, y, width, height)

    drawMasked(parentAlpha)
}

private fun Batch.drawMasked(parentAlpha: Float) {
    setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ZERO, GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA)
    drawSuper(this, parentAlpha)
    flush()

    Gdx.gl.glColorMask(true, true, true, true)
    setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_DST_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA)
    drawSuper(this, parentAlpha)
    flush()

    setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
}
```

}

---

### How Use:

```
val scissor = ScissorGroup(YourMask|YourBlackTextureRegion)
stage.addActor(scissor)
scissor.debug()
scissor.setBounds(50f, 0f, 50f, 50f)
scissor.addActor(a)
```

---

For the **mask** (the region where the actor will be displayed), **black color** is used with the transparency that you need, and where the transparency is, the actor will not be drawn

---

PS. Vel_daN: Love what You DO.